# Regex to separate environment variables into columns

Tags: regex

I have some environment variables

I want to split it into columns (using **regex only**) so for any normal env vars I could have just used `=` but in my case I have a var named `LS_COLORS` (see below) so how can I split my env vars into separate columns using regex in such case?

```
USER=idptest1
GROUP=support
HOST=beetle
LS_COLORS=no=00:fi=00:di=00;34:ln=00;36:pi=40;33:so=00;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=01;05;37;41:mi=01;05;37;41:ex=00;32:*.cmd=00;32:*.exe=00;32:*.com=00;32:*.btm=00;32:*.bat=00;32:*.sh=00;32:*.csh=00;32:*.tar=00;31:*.tgz=00;31:*.arj=00;31:*.taz=00;31:*.lzh=00;31:*.zip=00;31:*.z=00;31:*.Z=00;31:*.gz=00;31:*.bz2=00;31:*.bz=00;31:*.tz=00;31:*.rpm=00;31:*.cpio=00;31:*.jpg=00;35:*.gif=00;35:*.bmp=00;35:*.xbm=00;35:*.xpm=00;35:*.png=00;35:*.tif=00;35:
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
```

Can't I use something like `(?<=^[\w]+)=` to separate? If I use `^[\w]+=` it selects the `name=` (from name part only) which does not pick up from the value part.

You can check [here](http://regexr.com?2ve9r) if in a line all the 1st occurance of `=` is highlighted, my work will be done. Thanks

Comment: Define "regex only". You seem to be using some kind of split function. Why not use another one if it works better? What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @Qtax: Supposing I just need to highlight it http://regexr.com/?2ve9r. I am using java btw.

Comment: @Qtax: Mainly i want to use positive lookbehind somethin like `(?<=^[\w]+)=` as in place of pattern `[\w]` if i use some character it works, what if i want to give some pattern like this `(?<=^[\w]+)=` Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with something simple like:

```
^(.*?)=(.*)$
```

This has a non-greedy capturing group to capture the variable name and and a greedy capturing group to capture everything after the first '=' up to the end of line as the value.

If you have whitespace to dispose of then add

```
^\s*(.*?)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$
```

Comment: The regex selects all the lines, which i don't want, I only want to select the 1st occurrence of `=`

Comment: Perhaps it does in the regex implementation you have in mind (which isn't clear from your question), in Java and Scala which I use a lot, the default is line based matching which you can override to match on the entire input. This in Java is called DOTALL mode which can be enabled inline with (?s). I'm sure there is the equivalent flag for the implementation you have in mind.